# iptables rule slows everything down

Tags: iptables

I wanted to filter out bulk scrappers on my site and added a rule to iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 15 --connlimit-mask 32 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

Now my site loading content over a half minute, etc. Looks like only 1 thread allowed for loading contents.

I've removed the rule with the

```
iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 15 --connlimit-mask 32 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

but literally has no effect. Still on slow mode.

iptables -S:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N FORWARD_IN_ZONES
-N FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE
-N FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
-N FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-N FORWARD_direct
-N FWDI_public
-N FWDI_public_allow
-N FWDI_public_deny
-N FWDI_public_log
-N FWDO_public
-N FWDO_public_allow
-N FWDO_public_deny
-N FWDO_public_log
-N INPUT_ZONES
-N INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-N INPUT_direct
-N IN_public
-N IN_public_allow
-N IN_public_deny
-N IN_public_log
-N OUTPUT_direct
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -i eth0 -g FWDI_public
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -g FWDI_public
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -o eth0 -g FWDO_public
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -g FWDO_public
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_log
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_deny
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_allow
-A FWDI_public -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_log
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_deny
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_allow
-A INPUT_ZONES -i eth0 -g IN_public
-A INPUT_ZONES -g IN_public
-A IN_public -j IN_public_log
-A IN_public -j IN_public_deny
-A IN_public -j IN_public_allow
-A IN_public -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2244 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
```

How can I *undo* or fix this issue?

Comment: Why do you think the problem is with iptables? It doesn't look like an iptables problem.

Comment: I think the issue was that iptables did not flush after rules getting removed